# Why does strlen not work on mallocated memory?

Tags: c, malloc, strlen

I wrote the following code:

```
[all the required initialization]

printf("longueur de mid: %d\n",mid);

L = (char*) malloc((mid)*sizeof(char));

printf("longueur de L: %d\n",strlen(L));

[data treatment and free()]
```

And with the `printf` I got this result:

```
longueur de mid: 2
longueur de L: 3
```

Why do the outputs differ?

Comment: You want to read on what C-"strings" really are, as there is no data type "string" in C.

Comment: If you initialize with `null-characters` (zero), you will see the difference. i.e. `L = calloc(mid, sizeof(char));` and  `R = calloc((n - mid), sizeof(char));` (**note:** for storage of a string of `mid`, you must allocate `mid + 1` to provide room for the null-terminating character)

Comment: You've allocated memory but you've put nothing into it. So its contents are random, and might have any string length.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`strlen`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strlen) iterates until a null byte is found. `malloc` leaves the allocated space uninitialized, so a null byte may occur randomly. After all, it's undefined behavior due to the access of uninitialized memory.

Determining the size of a `malloc`ated block alone is not possible. Store the size in seperate variables like `Lsize` and `Rsize`.

---

Notes:

- [don't cast the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)
- multiplying by `sizeof(char)` is redundant as `sizeof(char) == 1`
- use `free` after `malloc`
- the corresponding format specifier for `size_t`, a.k.a. "return type of `strlen` and the `sizeof` operator" is `%zu`; `%d` is used on `int`s<sup>1</sup>

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> as @chux noted in the comments to this answer</sub>

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is pointless but `sizeof(L)` is not since that will work correctly even if the type of `L` is changed to something else such as `wchar_t`. Type names should almost never be passed to `sizeof`.

Comment: Suggested note to a fine answer: `printf("longueur de L: %d\n",strlen(L));` is UB - should be `%zu`.  `strlen()` returns a `size_t`, just like the type `malloc(size_t n)` takes.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I don't think that the problem is caused but a non initialization. Even when I use the data, this problem happens. For example when I reserved 2 * sizeof(char), I have always a third character in the string. Or maybe, the right thing to do is to initialize it with NULL.

Comment: @White Uhm, yes, the problem **is** caused by the access of uninitialized memory, just as I and the creator of the other answer mentioned. It's undefined behavior. Randomness at play (from the point of view of the C standard).

Answer (score 2):

As someone partially mentioned, strlen() converts the input fed to it into the correct memory location then that location is incremented by 1 until the null character is found. The problem with trying to use strlen() on a pointer from a malloc() call is that the data returned at the returned pointer can be anything depending on how your OS handles memory.

If you want your pointers to reference a guaranteed set of null characters when allocating memory, you can use this code:

```
L = calloc(1,mid+1); 
R = calloc(1,n - mid+1);
```

Then at least when you use strlen(), you'll get a zero.

If you must use malloc(), then you can use this code:

```
L = malloc(1,mid+1); 
R = malloc(1,n - mid+1); 
memset(L,0,mid);
memset(R,0,n - mid);
```

In both pieces of code, I assumed L and R are declared as `char*`.

and definitely use `free()` on all memory allocated with calloc and malloc or you can expect a memory leak which could lead into you restarting your computer.

If you want to put in a fixed number of bytes in memory in a quick way, use this after allocating memory:

```
memset(L,x,mid);
memset(R,x,n - mid);
```

but change x to any value other than zero or it will be null.

Here's a sample program that does more like what you expect:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(){
  int size=10;
  char* a=calloc(1,100); // allocate 100 null's and store pointer to them at 'a'
  printf("%d \n",size); // print wanted size
  printf("%d \n",strlen(a)); // print length of memory space which = 0
  memset(a,'A',size); // put 10 A's at the beginning of allocated memory
  printf("%d \n",strlen(a)); // print length again which now = 10
  printf("%s \n",a); // print memory (which is 10 A's)
  free(a); // free the memory
  return 0; 
}
```

The above compiled fine in my compiler with no warnings even with the compiler options `-Wall` and `-Wextra` enabled.